# Первое знакомство с YII2 advanced

Tags: yii2

Загрузил Yii2 advanced в site.ru/public_html/advanced на сервере.
Привык что загружается через index.php, тут не так.
Помогите плз разобраться (я в первый раз):
как попасть в на сайт и как в админку?

Comment: читал, всё что там описано, это то, как установить. Я же говорю, я в первый раз, если не трудно киньте плз ссылку

Answer (score 1):

оказывается всё просто! Нужно выполнить на сервере команду

```
php init
```

Спасибо добрым людям!

Comment: Спасибо добрым людям, которые пишут мануалы!